# Django wont store .00 on whole number decimal fields

Tags: django, model, save, rounding

I'm trying to force Django to always store numbers with 2 decimal places but if the number is a whole one then it isn't store the .00

```
def clean_myfield(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data['myfield']
    self.cleandecimal(data)
    return data

def cleandecimal(self, data):
    data = Decimal(data).quantize(Decimal('.01'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN)
    print 'data ', data
    return data
```

My prints always display as intended e.g. 4.00 but that gets stored as 4

How can I override the save method to store the value without rounding it?

Comment: What type is the field in the model?

Comment: sorry, they're all standard `models.DecimalField` or a custom type derived from `models.DecimalField`

Comment: Why is it a problem that its storing it as `4`? As long as it doesn't store `4.10` as `4`, I don't see the issue here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a representation issue. Decimal number stores numbers, not representations of them. Mathematically `1.00` is equal to `1`. So its possible that your database backend stores smallest truncated decimal without all zeros - so it's probably not Django, but db. If you want to force Django to always return decimal with two decimal places, you can overwrite the DecimalField:

```
class MyDecimalField(models.DecimalField):
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        places = kwargs.get('decimal_places', 2)
        self.q = Decimal(10) ** -places

    def to_python(self, value):
        value = super(self.__class__, self).to_python(value)

        if isinstance(value, Decimal):
            return value.quantize(self.q)

        else:
            return value
```

This will always return numbers with `decimal_places` as specified. You can use it the same way as you would normal `DecimalField`, like:

```
class FooModle(models.Model)
    number = MyDecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
```

Comment: Yeah after trying to enter a value in the db itself I thought it was db related. Thanks, I'll give that that a try now.

Answer (score 0):

Use `models.DecimalField(max_digits = 6, decimal_places = 2)` to store numbers with two decimal places.

Comment: model fields have `decimal_places=2` and `max_digits=10` already so something is rounding any value which is `.00`

Comment: Then probably there could be something wrong in the forms. Try printing **data** in **clean_myfield**. Check whether it is returning the value with two decimals.

Comment: Exactly. I always make stupid mistakes. So `data = self.cleandecimal(data)` in clean_myfield does it properly! But the model doesn't store the .00 decimal still. And if I directly edit the field in the db then it removes the .00 as well. this is a bigger problem

Comment: Have you tried defining your **cleandecimal** function outside the form class? I tried with the same coding as yours. Everything is working fine for me. The only difference is I defined the **cleandecimal** function outside form class.

Comment: @miki725 pointed out that the problem is in the db and not Django, so his answer solves my problems. thanks though